# Difference between multiphoton signal and, $n$-photon signal state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, quantum-information, quantum-optics, quantum-interpretations

I was reading decoy state quantum key distribution article, by Lo *et.al.* ([PRL paper](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.94.230504) , [PRA paper](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.72.012326)). In this article, authors have discussed the possibility of photon number splitting attack due to multiphoton signal emitted by the source. Later they have told about the source emitting n-photon signal state.

What is the difference between both the terminologies in the scenario discussed in the article? Is "multiphoton signal" referring to, 3 photons getting emitted simultaneously by the source? And does the "n-photon signal state" refer to, a signal containing n photons, each separated by timing information and independent of each other, emitted by the source?

Anyone with expertise in quantum optics and quantum key distribution please help me out clarifying this doubt.